# How to register as voice navigation app in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

How can I register my app as voice navigation app in Windows Phone 8.1?

I don't see any capabilities in app manifest which will allow my app to be target for map events.

Do I need to register for some protocol or file type extension to achieve this?

Comment: You mean like a GPS navigation with voice commands?

Comment: @neoproudek yes, I want to be able for my app to be registered as navigation app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out,

In app declarations I needed to define protocol declaration with name **ms-drive-to**.

Now the app shows up in list of available navigation apps.